# How come "oblivion" means "void"?

Tags: word-meaning, connotations

Oxford English Dictionary, 3rd edition (2004) says:

> **oblivion, *n.***
>
> **2. a.** The state or condition of being forgotten; (also, more generally) obscurity, nothingness, void, death.

However, what makes me puzzled is that although I've ever seen many times the word is used in such ways, I had had a hard time trying to find this definition, for almost every other dictionary I consulted didn't seem to refer to this sense, including the immediately previous version (1989) of OED:

> **oblivion, *n.***
>
> **2. a.** The state or condition of being forgotten. (Hence many phrases and fig. expressions.)

My questions are:

- Is the sense like "obscurity, nothingness, void, death" emerging (or recognized) this recently?
- Is it a unique connotation tied to *oblivion*, or generally carried by the concept of "forgottenness" in English (or, perhaps European) language so that they don't need to clarify?

Comment: You might search for examples of the phrase *blown into oblivion*. For example, [***The White Room - D.C. Charters - Google Books***](https://books.google.com/books?id=TxZuz-3xxmEC&pg=PA310&lpg=PA310&dq=blown+into+oblivion&source=bl&ots=2mWI5nqGkW&sig=uYe3Be7Qfv7SnT03StLx2uEAx0k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidwMP5tsHKAhUY02MKHXR5AFE4ChDoAQhGMAc#v=onepage&q=blown%20into%20oblivion&f=false) could be read as *void*.

Comment: Also, [***Bone Hunter - Sarah Andrews - Google Books***](https://books.google.com/books?id=OJzcwYCKGrMC&pg=PT244&lpg=PT244&dq=blown+into+oblivion&source=bl&ots=jvzZ0hq-2O&sig=9ZbETYAjzWGL6ydfuM2PLxWTMVw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidwMP5tsHKAhUY02MKHXR5AFE4ChDoAQhJMAg#v=onepage&q=blown%20into%20oblivion&f=false). Not void but definitely nothingness and destruction.

Comment: @user3169 Thanks. Actually what I mean is not that I don't know this usage, in fact, I've ever run into those phrases many times while my dictionaries seemingly ignore it.

Comment: Maybe it is pop culture that didn't make it to literary circles...

Comment: Can you give an example of its use in the sense 'void'? Something which has been completely forgotten, relegated to *oblivion*, may be said to exist in a *void*, in a figurative emptiness; but that doesn't imply that the two words mean the same thing.

Comment: @StoneyB - How about this one? _Eventually, like the kite tail, they become so small and distant that they are simply lost in the **oblivion of space**, swallowed up by the universe._ (Source: Becca Jackson, _The Way of Tea and Justice_, 2014)

Comment: broccoli forest - Someone has suggested this question would be a better fit for our sister site, ELU. (The difference between the two sites is described [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/what-is-the-difference-between-elu-and-ell/3723#3723).) It's your call – I can leave it here, or I can migrate it to ELU. Let me know.

Comment: @J.R. Hmm ... I'm afraid Rev. Stevens' metaphors are more remarkable for feeling than for precision: this seems to me a very dubious transfer of the viewer's *oblivion* (obliviousness to the prayers) to the field of vision. In any case, to say that the prayers are invisible in the vastness of space is not the same thing as to say they are invisible in the emptiness of space.

Comment: @Stoney - That may be true about the context of that particular sentence, but couldn't we borrow the same language? _In 2012, the Voyager I probe left the solar system and entered the oblivion of space_. I don't find anything odd about that use of the word _oblivion_.

Comment: @J.R. It's not odd; it's just factually wrong. If Voyager 1 had been swallowed by interstellar space and thereby disappeared from human consciousness, *oblivion* would be acceptable; but NASA's still receiving signals from it.

Comment: @JR I think one could only accept Voyager I entering the **oblivion** of space, if one believed that Christopher Columbus sailed into the **oblivion** of the horizon (poetic licence).  We've just never been where Voyager is going.  **Unknown**? Yes. **Oblivion**? Maybe not, it'll probably run into something else out there, we just don't know what **that** is. I agree that **oblivion** has the connotation of **nonexistence** and space being the **great void** certainly has a lot of **nothingness** (as far as we know)

Comment: @StoneyB Most recently I came across this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUMSMDX5iQc Note that "void" is a special word in this game, so not very ideal according to my title, but either way you can see it has nothing with what I think standard understanding of "forgotten". Nothingness? Extinction? Obliteration? Is "nonexistence" better for the question as Peter suggested?

Comment: @J.R. I'm fine with migration. I just couldn't decide whether my question came from the nature of English or my limited knowledge of it.

Comment: Oblivion, in the context of the video you linked, definitely feels like a *cool* word used in a sense that doesn't really fit with its meaning; this happens now and then in fiction. I don't know much about StarCraft, but it looks like **Void** is used in the same way: the Wikipedia page says *"along with hybrids and beings from the Void"* but clearly that "void" isn't emptyness if there are beings in it. It just sounds fantasy-like.

Answer (score 1):

**Void** and **oblivion** have always had close meanings. The 1828 Webster's dictionary offers this definition for *oblivion*:

> 1. Forgetfulness; cessation of remembrance.
> 2. A forgetting of offenses, or remission of punishment.

And this for *void*:

> 1. To vacate; to annul; to nullify; to render of no validity or effect.
> 2. Free; clear; as a conscience void of offense.

As you can see, both words have long referred to *wiping something out*, or to an *absence of something*, or a *legal annulment*. From there, oblivion has taken on another meaning of void, namely:

> VOID, n. An empty space; a vacuum.

Examples of usage:

> "Oblivion refers to things forgotten... things are lost in oblivion." -- *G.F. Graham*, English Synonymes, 1867
>
> "...deeper than oblivion do we bury the incensing relicks of it." -- *W. Shakespeare*, All's Well That Ends Well, c1605
>
> "...the eye even sought relief, in vain, by attempting to pierce the illimitable void of heaven..." -- *J.F. Cooper*, The Last of the Mohicans, 1826
>
> "And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep." -- *Genesis 1:2*, KJV Bible

Comment: Curiously use of vacuum in industrial processess started about the 19c, probably leading to the adoption of the newer definiton of the word 'void'. Note that it is total speculation on my part.

Looking at the etemology of the two words the word oblivion has its origins in the meaning 'to forget'. Void on the other hand comes from words meaning 'avoid' or 'vacate'.

Answer (score -1):

Oblivion family of words consists of the oblivious too
"Word Family
"oblivious
oblivionoblivious
the "oblivion" family
Usage Examples"
Oblivion is the state of being forgotten. If you slip into oblivion after selling one record, then your only hope is becoming a "VH1 one-hit wonder."
Oblivion can also mean "total forgetfulness" — like what patients with dementia or new parents feel. If you find yourself putting the crackers in the fridge and milk in the cupboards, or forgetting your own phone number, you might be experiencing oblivion. Enjoy it while it lasts."

Vide https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/oblivious
I also easily located the above words at AHD.